# How to Change Xcode "Add Documentation" Back to Block Style Commenting

Tags: xcode

**Question**

Does anyone know how to change the `Add Documentation` single line commenting style in Xcode 11 back to the block commenting style of Xcode 10?

**Context**

Xcode 10 provided us with the ability to document functions and methods with either `Editor` -> `Structure` -> `Add Documentation` by pressing <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and this would insert a  comment above a function or method with the traditional C block comments style to permit easy documentation as in the filled-out example:

```
/**
 Flashes the garage door opener light (built in) to give
 indication as to what might be going on.

 For example, we might flash it 0.25 second interval for 2
 seconds to indicate that the garage door is going to close
 or we might flash it with an SOS pattern if the
 garage door is jammed

 @param flashPattern    flashPattern enumerated to indicate
                        what pattern to flash on the garage
                        door light to indicate status
                        of the garage door opener
 */
void FlashGarageDoorOpenerLight(GarageDoorOpenerLightFlashPatterns flashPattern) {
```

Xcode pulls the parameters out of the function declaration and adds in the `@param` for each. Just tab between the description and parameter place holders and fill them out. This *was really great* albeit not perfect...

Now `Add Documentation` Xcode 11 puts end-of-line comment style slashes /// in front of every line:

```
/// Flashes the garage door opener light (built in) to give
/// indication as to what might be going on.
///
/// For example, we might flash it 0.25 second interval for 2
/// seconds to indicate that the garage door is going to close
/// or we might flash it with an SOS pattern if the
/// garage door is jammed
///
/// @param flashPattern flashPattern    enumerated to indicate
///                                     what pattern to flash on the garage
///                                     door light to indicate status
///                                     of the garage door opener
void FlashGarageDoorOpenerLight(GarageDoorOpenerLightFlashPatterns flashPattern) {
```

Having all these extra /// on every line is visually distracting and there does not appear to be any way to revert Xcode back to the simple and clean block comment style, hence this question.

Comment: BTW, I do have "Block Comment for Xcode" which helps but is not the solution sought.